# How to get back deleted data using sudo rm -rf

Tags: sudo, data-recovery

I have deleted folder using sudo rm -rf. How to recover back?

Im not able to find it in trash folder

Answer (score 1):

The 'rm' command does not employ the Trashcan mechanism of Unity.  You may be able to employ some of the tools mentioned in [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files), however it might already be too late - one of the first steps in a situation like this is "stop using the hard disk"

Answer (score 0):

First you should mount the partition in read only mode to prevent the OS accidentally overwriting the deleted content.

You could try it with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). Although there is "Photo" in the title it can recover any files. You need a second partition in which PhotoRec then writes the recovered files. Because it can't check how recent the file was deleted, it will recover files which you might have deleted ages ago (depending on the usage of the drive).